# Array sequence in Rails not converted properly when passed to angular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby

I'm using Rails 4.2 with angularjs in the current application. Response in Rails controller action is generated as below which is sent as api Response. This api is being consumed by angular to display content accordingly.

**Response from controller**

```
{
"switch": {},
"collections": {
    "valid_numbers": 1..12,

}}
```

Angularjs code which works on that response data.

```
$scope.PortFilter = function (data) {
  return $scope.data.collections.valid_numbers.indexOf(data.PortNumber) > -1;
};
```

Html code from Rails

```
<tr ng-repeat="port in data.switch.ports_attributes| filter:PortFilter" display_port_number="{{port.display_port_number}}">
  <td style="vertical-align: middle" nowrap="nowrap">
    {{port.display_port_number}}
  </td>
```

As seen in the firebug, response from api in browser contains "valid_numbers": 1..12 rather an Array of integers from 1 to 12.
Below response works properly with hard coded as seen in below snippet, values are coming as an array.

```
{
"switch": {},
"collections": {
    "valid_numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],

}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say simply provide an array in the response rather than a range:

```
"valid_numbers": (1..12).to_a, # or [*1..12]
```

From what I've seen a range is simply converted into a string:

```
(1..12).to_json
#=> "\"1..12\""
```

Whereas an array stays an array:

```
(1..12).to_a.to_json
#=> "[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]"
```

Comment: Array is an alternative to resolve this, my concern was i have seen these type of code snippets working in rails 3.2. So was wondering is something in the framework changed.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ruby on Rails 3.2. I've started using Ruby on Rails on version 4.1. So I can't comment on the previous behaviour. However if the previous had a different result something must have changed, otherwise you would've gotten the same output. The question is does it matter? You're working with the new behaviour, not with the old behaviour. Meaning that you should use what currently works, not what previously worked.